# Putting a link with a query as a parameter of a get request

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

So basically I'm trying to create a very simple server which with take a request which include a link to be stored, but my problem is, is if that link contains a query with an &, everything past the & is not stored because the server thinks it's an entirely different parameter within the query. I'll clear this up with an example, but firstly here is the code:

```
package com.something.tomcatServer;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class javaQuery extends HttpServlet {

    String storedId = null;

    public void storeId(String u){
        storedId = u;
    }

    public String retrieveId(){
        return storedId;
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {



    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String request = req.getParameter("request");
        if(request.equalsIgnoreCase("sendId")){
            String url = req.getParameter("id");
            if(url != null){
                storeId(url);
            }else{
                resp.getWriter().println("ERROR: No ID was inputted to store for the sendId request.");
            }
        }else if(request.equalsIgnoreCase("retrieveId")){
            String retrievedId = retrieveId();
            resp.getWriter().println(retrievedId);
        }

    }
}
```

So basically in the doGet it's saying there are two request types "sendId" and "retrieveId". "retrieveId" works perfectly fine, it just retrieves the last stored URL, but sendId doesn't work in this case:

Example: localhost:8080/javaQuery?request=sendId&url= http://m.yahoo.com/?.tsrc=yahoo&mobile_view_default=true,

now if I do localhost:8080/javaQuery?request=retrieveId
it will only output http://m.yahoo.com/?.tsrc=yahoo, because of the & in the url. I hope this makes sense. What I'm asking is how I could go about fixing this problem as I am not completely sure. Any insight whatsoever is helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to encode it so the url you want to pass is interpreted properly as a single value being passed and not several distinct values.

This should get you started...

```
 import java.net.URLEncoder;
 try {
     URLEncoder.encode(YOUR_URL_HERE, "UTF-8")
 } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();  
 }
```

Comment: I understand your answer, but my only question is where I would encode the URL if I cannot fully retrieve it in the first place. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: This is code you might use in the caller, not the server. See my answer for the explanation :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your server is probably (I haven't looked at the code) behaving fine. Your problem is trying to do something that's not valid in the URL format. "Special" characters in URLs need to be encoded, unless they're being used for their "special" role. The `&` (and the `?` for that matter) in your `url=` value need to be URL-encoded. Naively this just means replacing them with `%26` and `%3F` respectively, but you should pass the whole value through a URL-encoding library to catch any other rogue characters that may arise.